# syntax error problem on END keyword with MySQL code

Tags: mysql, create-function, mysql-function

**Why do I get a syntax error when everything looks fine. The error position on the MySQL workbench is indicated.
I have checked alot of questions, but found no answer. I know it will be a minor problem but I can't figure it out**

````````````````
SELECT * FROM classicmodels.customers;


DELIMITER $$

create function CustomerLevel( credit decimal(10,2))

returns varchar(20) deterministic
begin 
    
    declare customerLevel varchar(20);
    
    if (credit > 50000) then set customerLevel = 'PLATINUM';
 
       else if (credit >= 50000 and credit <= 10000) then set customerLevel = 'GOLD';
    
    else IF (credit < 10000) then set customerLevel ='SILVER';
    
    end if;
    
    return (customerLevel);
 
end; -- this is where the syntax error code is
 $$ DELIMITER ;
 
 

/* 
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
 for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10
 */
```````````````
````````````````

Comment: [IF statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html) - `ELSEIF` does not contain a space.

Comment: `(credit >= 50000 and credit <= 10000)` - this is true never. Swap operators.

Comment: Exactly, I know it would be a little oversight. Thanks